# Get a set of maximum number of dissimilar arrays

Tags: python

I have an array A of length n, each element of this array(say Wi) is an array is an array of length 10. There is a function, match_check(Wi, Wj) defined as :

```
def match_check(Wi, Wj):
  n = len(Wi)
  num_matches =0
  for i in range(n):
    if (round(Wi[i],4)== round(Wj[i]),4):
        num_matches +=1
  if (num_matches >= 3):
    return True 
  else :
    False
```

I want to get set of maximum number of elements from this array A, such that for no two elements in this set match_check is True. I have thought of this as a DP problem and written the following solution.

```
def maximum_arrays(start,end ,curr_items=[], match_dict={}, lookup_dict={}):
 key = str(start) + "|" + str(end) 
 
 if (lookup_dict.get(key)):
    return lookup_dict[key]
 if (start == end ):
    for items in curr_items:
        match_key = str(start)+ ":" + str(items)
        if(match_dict[match_key]):
            lookup_dict[key] = len(curr_items)
            return lookup_dict[key]
    lookup_dict[key] = 1 + len(curr_items)
    return lookup_dict[key]

 match_flag = False
 for items in curr_items:
    match_key = str(start)+":" + str(items)
    if (match_dict.get(match_key)):
        match_flag = True
        break
 if (match_flag):
    lookup_dict[key] = maximum_arrays(start+1,end, curr_items,match_dict, lookup_dict)
 else:
    curr_items_new   = curr_items + [start]
    lookup_dict[key] = max(1 + maximum_arrays(start+1,end, curr_items_new,match_dict, lookup_dict),
                      maximum_arrays(start+1,end, curr_items,match_dict, lookup_dict))

     
 return lookup_dict[key]
```

Where match_dict is contains the result of match_check for all possible pairs of indexes from the array A. But I doubt that dynamic programming would help here and the solution would be O(2^n), since we have to evaluate for all possible cases(keeping and dropping each element in the set).

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm which takes `O(n^2)` would be to first build an adjacency matrix for these arrays by simply applying match_check to every couple of arrays. An edge will be added iff the function match_check returned False.
Then, the problem reduces to finding the maximum clique within the graph and returning its size, a thing which can be done in `O(n^2)`.

Here is a simple demo:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

def match_check(Wi, Wj):
  n = len(Wi)
  num_matches =0
  for i in range(n):
    if round(Wi[i],4) == round(Wj[i],4):
        num_matches +=1
  if (num_matches >= 3):
    return True 
  else :
    return False
    

check_arr = [list(10*np.random.rand(5)) for k in range(10)]
n = len(check_arr)
graph_adjacency_mat = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i==j:
            continue
        graph_adjacency_mat[i][j] = not match_check(check_arr[i],check_arr[j])
        graph_adjacency_mat[j][i] = graph_adjacency_mat[i][j]

G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(graph_adjacency_mat)
print(max([len(clique) for clique in nx.find_cliques(G)]))
```

Note that here I've used the find_cliques function from NetworkX which is NOT `O(n^2)`  (but `O(3^(n/3))`) because the function max_clique of NetworkX seems to be discarded. You can easily implement max_clique by applying BFS/DFS on the graph starting from every vertex and saving the maximum clique found thus far.